# Multiple view when reloading data from collection view

Tags: swift, collections, view

Im having a weird situation when reloading a collection view, before reloading I remove all object from the source then fetch it after that I'm calling reloadData on my collection and for some reason the collection is adding view but never remove them. (the dataSource doesn't have duplicate the array is always correct)

When I call a reload :

```
        viewModel.reloadActivities()
        activityCollection.reloadData()
```

This method in the viewModel fetch the data and replace the array used by the data source :

```
    func reloadActivities() {
        activities.removeAll()
        fetchActivities()
    }
```

Here is an Activity Cell:

```
    func configure(with activity: Activity) {
        self.displayActivityCell(with: activity)
    }

    func displayActivityCell(with activity: Activity) {
        let background = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 100))
        background.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)
        contentView.addSubview(background)

        let label = UILabelFactory(text: activity.getMessage()).color(.black).draw()
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.topAnchor == background.topAnchor + 10
        label.leadingAnchor == background.leadingAnchor
        label.trailingAnchor == background.trailingAnchor
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
```

But here is the result if I call the reload X times...

[Result when I call reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnS37.jpg)

Any hint why the reloadData doesn't "clean" the added contentView?

Thanks

Comment: Every time you reload the data, your displayActivityCell being called over and over again. It is not good place to add an UIView instance to your cell. So add your views in init method and hide/show when you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the object and UI elements are separated. Reload data is only for data. Do you call `configure(with activity: Activity)` in the view controller's cellForRow at indexpath ? if so, it will always create a new background view and adding it into contentView's subview.

How about moving out the `background` and label to cell's init method.
Inside the `displayActivityCell` function, you should only customise things that are changing, like this ...

```swift
func displayActivityCell(with activity: Activity) {
    background.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)
    label.text = activity.getMessage()
}
```